# How to change color of Flutter ButtonBar in a Scaffold?

Tags: flutter

How can I change the color of a `ButtonBar` in Flutter? There isn't a color in `ButtonBarTheme` as far as I can tell. I am trying to do something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  body: Center(child: Text('foo')),
  // Somehow get the color of these buttons different to backgroundColor
  persistentFooterButtons: _buildTextButtons(),
);
```

The best I can think of at the moment is to somehow reimplement the persistent footer buttons myself, but that is ugly. The problem seems to be that the `Scaffold` `backgroundColor` property is used in multiple places, yet is defined in a single widget. This means I can't wrap it in a `Theme` and override it piecemeal either, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think it's the ButtonTextTheme that has the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I might have found an answer. I had been using both the `bottomNavigationBar` and the `persistentFooterButtons`. `persistentFooterButtons` are wrapped in a `ButtonBar`, which appears to limit your styling options.

`bottomNavigationBar` is a single widget, though, so you can fiddle with it. I switched to just build my own `persistentFooterButtons` after all.

(I had to edit this from my app, so it might not be copy/paste ready.)

```
Widget _buildNavigationBar(BuildContext ctx, Color barColor) {
    List<Widget> actions = [
      // We need the first element to be big, to push everything to the right.
      Spacer(),
    ];
    actions.addAll(_buildTextButtons(ctx));

    Widget actionContainer = ColoredBox(
      color: barColor,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: actions,
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        actionContainer,
        // I use this to make space for ads.
        Container(
          color: barColor,
          height: 50,
        ),
      ],
    );
}

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  body: Center(child: Text('foo')),
  // removed this persistentFooterButtons: _buildTextButtons(),
  // and replaced with this:
  bottomNavigationBar: _buildNavigationBar(ctx),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also wrap that ButtonBar into Container and After that, you can make any type of changes to that ButtonBar, like coloring etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).